# How addOnFailureListener works in FusedLocationProviderClient and why addOnSuccessListener doesn't work?

Tags: android, kotlin

I need to get last location phone, but I don't understand why it's not work. There my code, can you tell me what I doing bad.

```
private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

var lastLocation: Location? = null
fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context)
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                context,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
           fusedLocationClient.flushLocations()
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
                listener -> lastLocation = listener
     
            }.addOnFailureListener{
                
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any problem with permissions ? If not, can you try to log something inside onSuccessListener and onFailureListener. Just to see if it goes inside of 'em because it is like "IF" and "ELSE" one has to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Move code out side if condition

```
fusedLocationClient.flushLocations()
            fusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
                listener -> lastLocation = listener
     
            }.addOnFailureListener{
                
            }
```

- Check Location permissions from app info in your device or emulator
- Check enable location in device
- open  Google map to save location